# Correct selection of table fields where value=null

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

There is a list of fields (name1, name2, name3) and i need select a field which value is null

I try

```
select @Listname from Table where (@List is null)
```

but this is not correct
it will create the command

```
select name1, name2, name3 from table where (name1, name2, name3 is null)
```

is null not formed correctly and it will select all values, but i need select field which value= null.

for example my list

```
List<string> NameList = new List<string>() { name1, name2, name3 };
```

value of this fiels
name1=joe, name2=doe, name3=null
my select should be look like 
`select name3 frome NameTabe where name3 is null`

I use mssql and write on C# like

```
var nullValue = SqlClient.Main.CreateCommand(@"
                select @nameList 
                from NameTabe
                where (@nameList is null)"
                , new SqlParam("nameList", nameList) { Array = true }
                )
                .ExecScalars<string>();
```

Comment: _but i need select field which value= null_ ... I don't really get what you mean here. Could you provide some sample data and the desired result?

Comment: i try, name1=joe, name2=doe, name3=null, and my select should be look like ```select name3 frome NameTabe where name3 is null```

Comment: That's pretty pointless. If you always just select the column which is `NULL` you will never get back anything else than `NULL`, regardless which field you are testing.

Comment: @EvgeniyBojenov `where (@List is null)` won't generate anything, it checks whether the parameter is null or not. `where (name1, name2, name3 is null)` isn't a valid query. I suspect you use a microORM like *Dapper* so the query isn't really about SQL Server and SQL

Comment: your right.... i need select this name and fill value of this fields

Comment: @EvgeniyBojenov if you use a microORM, the list should *not* be null. I'm surprised the microORM doesn't throw an exception. The clause `where (@nameList is null)` eg in Dapper wouldn't make any sense. On the other hand, `Where (somefield in @List)` would be translated to `where somefield in ('value1','value2','value3'...)`

Comment: @EvgeniyBojenov which microORM are you using? Where did `SqlParam` and `ExecScalars` come from?

Comment: If you are getting database from a database use DBNULL.Value instead of null.  Your List object may not be null but instead contain no items so also check for count == zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a query like:

```
select (case when name1 is null then 'name1'
             when name2 is null then 'name2'
             when name3 is null then 'name3'
        end)
from t
where name1 is null or name2 is null or name3 is null;
```

Perhaps starting with the right syntax will help you construct the query.

Note that having multiple columns with the same information, only distinguished by a number (i.e. `name1`, `name2`, etc.) is a sign of a problem with the data model.  I suspect that if you had the right data model, it would be much simpler to accomplish what you really need to do.

Answer (score 0):

you should use dynamic query like this :

```
select 'select '+case when name1 is null then name1+',' else '' end+
                +case when name2 is null then name2+',' else '' end+
                +case when name3 is null then name3+',' else '' end 
                +' from table' 
from table
```

if you need filter data by the null value you can use this where cluase :

```
where name1+name2+name3 is null -- at least 1 of them is null
```